# how to re-order etherpad toolbar buttons?

Tags: etherpad

I want to reorder etherpad toolbar buttons. For inbuilt etherpad buttons, it could be done with `exports.toolbar` I found then comes the ones added by plugins using `exports.eejsBlock_editbarMenuLeft` hook. can anyone guide me re-order the ones added by `exports.eejsBlock_editbarMenuLeft` hook? Though the actual order I want falls in both sets e.g. Print, Import, Superscript, Bold etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `postToolbarInit` hook and modify the order using jQuery once all buttons are set.

```
exports.postToolbarInit = function (hook, context){

  var $superscript = $("#editbar li.superscript");
  var $subscript = $("#editbar li.subscript");

  var $underline = $("#editbar li[data-key=\"underline\"]");

  $subscript.insertAfter($underline.next("li"));
  $superscript.insertAfter($underline.next().next());
};
```